# Calculate Exponent Bits

Tags: floating-point

I have something to ask about the bit's exponent
[image: As in the picture]The meaning of `32`, is to count from `0` to `31`.

However they will be divided into two parts positive and negative parts, which have a total of 32 (`-16`.....`+15`).

My question, why is it negative `-16`, can I swap it like (`-15`....`+16`),

and how can i find out the max of negative `-16` and a maximum of positive `15`?

Some possibilities like
(`-11`.....`+20`) = `32`, and so on.

Comment: The *bias* value — which, yes, is 15 for half-precision or binary16 format — is one of the fundamental defining properties of a floating-point type, along with the sizes and locations of the sign, exponent, and significand fields.  So, no, you can't change it, because by doing so you would be creating a new, different, incompatible floating-point format.  (But if you're willing to create a new format, then yes, you can choose whatever values you want!)

Comment: And the actual range for binary16 is closer to the range you were asking about. The raw exponent values run from 0 to 31, but after subtracting the bias of 15, the actual exponent values run from -15 to +16.  But that's not quite right, either, because raw exponent values of 0 and 31 are special.  When the raw exponent value is 0, that indicates we're dealing with *subnormal* values, which have an exponent of -14, not -15.  And when the raw exponent value is 31, that indicates we're dealing with the special Inf and Nan values.

Comment: The exponents use a [biasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) scheme to represent positive and negative; they are **not** [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: @Steve KTT hi sir, thank you for answering the question, does it mean that `-16.....+15` is already a floating point format

Comment: @SteveSummit I think I can do the math to get the reason why the starting point starts at `-16`

Comment: @Steven KTT hi sir sorry before I did not understand it, that's what I'm asking, why does it start from `-16`.... and ends with `+15`, if we count by index `-16, -15, ..... 0 ... 14 , 15`. has a total of 32, but why does it start with `-16 and end with `15`

Comment: It does not start with -16.   The exponents for binary16 run from -15 to +16 (although the usable range is from -14 to +15).  The notation "-16 <---> +15" in the figure is simply wrong.  (Where did that figure come from?  The rest of the information in it is correct.)

Comment: @SteveSummit hi sir, sorry before I didn't read your chat, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  is about [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) encoding.

> however they will be divided into two parts positive and negative parts, which have a total of 32 (-16.....+15)

No.  The 5 *exponent bits* are not divided into two parts (-16.....+15).  The **"(-16.....+15)"** note in the picture **misleads**.

Instead think of the 5 *exponent bits* as a *biased exponent* value [0...31] that have different meaning depending on value.

1. [1...30] (normals):  The *implied* significant bit is `1` and the *exponent* is *biased exponent* - *exponent bias*.

```
exponent = biased_exponent - 15
```

2. [0...0] (sub-normals): The *implied* significant bit is `0` and the *exponent* is *1* - *exponent bias*.

```
exponent = 1 - 15
```

3. [31...31]: Special.  The value is infinity or a not-a-number.

---

> my question, why is it negative -16, can I swap it like (-15....+16),

It is not -16.  Considering it as "-15....+16" is more correct, aside for the edge cases.

---

> how can i find out the max of negative -16 and a maximum of positive 15

The most negative binary exponent is -14 and the maximum positive is 15.

---

The maximum [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) is

1.1111 1111 111<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>30 - 15</sup> or 65504.0

The minimum *normal* binary16 is

1.0000 0000 000<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>-14</sup> or ≈ 6.10 × 10<sup>−5</sup>.

The minimum non-zero binary16 is

0.0000 0000 001<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>-14</sup> or ≈ 5.96 × 10<sup>−8</sup>.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for answering my question, i have something to ask, before it was `2⁵ = 32`, and the raw value was `(0..31)`, why it became `(1..30)`

Comment: Kangkue, Answer divided  [0..31] into 3 sub-ranges, [1...30] , [0...0] and [31...31]`.  Each sub-range direct the interpretation of the 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

**If** *the ranges were indeed as you found them,* then one could justify this as follows: The mantissa values `(1.m)_2` where `m` is the bit string of the stored mantissa part, takes values between 1 and 2. So the range of encoded numbers is from `1*2^-16=2^-16` to shortly before `2*2^15=2^16`, which is quite symmetric in the exponents.

**However,** *the bias 15 shifts the "raw" range `0..31` to `-15..16`,* simple subtraction, no super-secret decoder necessary. The number zero is represented by all bits zero, including the exponent bits (also the subnormal numbers have all exponent bits zero). On the opposite end, all exponent bits one is taken to encode infinity and "fubar" results (NaN).

> So the exponent range that is available to encode normal numbers is `-14..15`.

By the above logic, this gives "4 times more large numbers than small numbers". On the other hand, with the subnormals, this is balanced to some degree (if one cares for such a balance, it's all quite arbitrary).

Comment: That's not quite right.  The "real" exponent values for [half precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) run from -14 to +15.  And then the [subnormals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) let you get down to 0.

Comment: That is true if you shave off the encodings for denormal numbers, infinity and NaN's.

Comment: I still don't know where you got 1*2^-16.

Comment: I just used the exponent range in the question, which is directly taken from the data in the cited image. But even there the table is quite inconsistent with the calculation below it. 0..31 with bias 15 gives -15..16, shaving off the extremes for zero and the infinities gives -14..15, thus providing more large numbers than very small numbers. I should probably amend the answer with that.

Comment: @Disagree about being _quite arbitrary_,  Bias is such that `1/min_normal` is near `max` and not infinite. and `1/max` is just under `min_normal` and non-zero.